# Issues with relative/absolute path

Tags: php, path, relative-path, realpath, pathinfo

I've searched ways to do it so it would work but none of them seemed to work for all paths, so I was wondering if you could give me a direction on how to do this:

This is the structure:

```
Home Directoy
   config.php
   index.php
   includes/
      user_login.php
      applicant_track.php
   ucp/
      index.php
```

When I am trying to include includes/user_login.php in ucp/index.php it doesn't let me and says that it cannot find the file, my code is in ucp/index.php is:

```
if(!defined('root_path'))
{
    define('root_path', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
}

include(root_path . '\config.php');

switch($_GET["a"])
{
    case null: include(root_path . '\index.php'); break;
    case "login": include(root_path . '\includes\user_login.php'); break;
}
```

This is what I get:

```
Warning: include(E:\xampp\htdocs\aod_panel\ucp\config.php): failed to open stream:
```

I'd be happy for an advise on how to fix this.

Comment: Tell me actual path Where that config.php is located.

Comment: Have you tried: `include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/user_login.php';`

Comment: Your index.php code is in \ucp, so root_path is \ucp, but config.php is not in \ucp...

Comment: The config.php is in the home directory., and I haven't tried it, SuperDJ, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following path

```
define('root_path', realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
```

instead of your code for defining real path. As your folder structure is like that.

See your index.php is in `ucp` folder but you want path of config.php. So go back one directory and get config.php path.

Comment: Unfortunately now I get an issue with displaying template files from Home Directory/template, it doesn't find them (aka CSS references and such which are brought from here `{include file='header.html'}`, aka I use Smarty to redirect the templates and they don't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your root path does not points to the actual root of your project. Your actual root is someLocation/yourProject.

the root you have defined is someLocation/yourProject/includes/

Then you want to include file in another folder. Hence it cannot find it. Define the root of your path to your actual project root and not inside includes directory.

To do this, you can define the root path in your config file and read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely one of your other scripts includes the config.php without proper path. Set up your include paths using the following code

```
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $root_path);
```

Also change the include to require_once to prevent multiple includes.